# How can I execute the same lines of code after all scenarios in specific feature files in Karate?

Tags: cucumber, karate

How can I execute the same few lines of code after every specific scenario?
For example, we have 'Background' defined at the top of our feature files.  Is there a 'Footer' or something similar?
Since I only want to execute this code on specific features, not our entire repository, I would need to add it to the specific feature file, but I don't want to add it to every single scenario in the feature file, I just want to add it once.

We have background, which executes at the beginning of each scenario:

**Background:**

*to start do this

to start do this as well*

I want something like this, to execute at the end of each scenario:

**Footer:**

*to finish do this

to finish do this as well*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an `afterScenario` hook: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

```
Background:
* configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.log('hello') }
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but it wasn't quiet what I was looking for.  However I'm using it and have it working the way I need it to.  Using that approach, I can set the afterScenario to call a feature file, passing any arguments I need.  Then I have that feature file do the work I want it to do, which is karate code, not javascript code

Comment: @CoreySnow of course. I was confident you would figure that out once you looked at the docs. the entry point is a JS function, but then you typically would delegate to a feature file via `karate.call('some.feature')`

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for calling a scenario within a separate feature file, even when placed in a different folder:

```
* configure afterFeature = function(){ karate.call(utilPath + "/helperFile.feature@helperTest"); }
```

This is assuming you have defined the "utilPath" either in your `karate-config.js` file or in the background.